# Websphere MQ XMS Event Poll Time

Tags: ibm-mq

I use websphere mq xms.net infrastructure to async message listening.My problem is sometimes there are messages in queue but xms cannot read them on time and waiting 1,2... 5 minutes wait and then get the message.Is there any configuration on xms for that something like event poll interval time ...?Sometimes I got message directly sometimes not?

Comment: What version of MQ and XMS are using? Are you able to receive the messages in the queue with any other MQ application?

Comment: 8.0.0.8 version I use,yes I can get message with amqmdnet ,I try to set IBM.XMS.XMSC.RTT_BROKER_PING_INTERVAL and  IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL that time xms not read the messages

Comment: So, can you confirm: your application is can receive messages if XMSC.RTT_BROKER_PING_INTERVAL and XMSC.WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL properties are not set?

Comment: I set these intervals any case.But If I not set these intervals I can take message .But how can I arrange event check limti?

Answer (score 1):

You are using XMS .NET version 8.0.0.8. I am not sure what value you have set for the XMSC.WMQ_PROVIDER_VERSION property. The default value is "unpspecified" as documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/xmsc_wmq_provider_version.htm).

**Update:**
Apologies. I just checked documentation and IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL is valid for MQ 7 and above.

However XMSC.RTT_BROKER_PING_INTERVAL property is not valid when connecting MQ queue manager. It is valid only for Real Time Transport of Message Broker and RTT is no longer supported.

Are you connecting to MQ v6 queue manager by any chance?

I suggest you to not set IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL property. The messages should be delivered as soon as they arrive in queue and application is ready to receive.

Comment: I dont have to change it.What should I set WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL in 8.0.0.8?

Comment: I suggest not to set WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL. I don't think I have ever set this property. When using message listener, messages should be delivered to application immediately after they arrive in queue and application is ready to receive.